# How can i get root permission only for application

Tags: android, permissions, root

Is it possible to get root access for only one application? the idea behind is to i did't want to open permission dialog for accessing some feature of application like storage permission like vise.

is it possible via running command Runtime, but i am not sure this is working or not for android 14 OS device.

```
Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

Also getting **FACTORY_TEST** permission from google document but this will not help me.

Comment: Just to make sure you got this - to get root access your device must be rooted first. There's no system feature/API for regular app to get elevated privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You Have Marked Code

```
Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

This code will also work in android-14 but it is not a good way.

Instead You can use the libsu by topjohnwu (magisk-official)

Here you can find it
[topjohnwu/libsu](https://github.com/topjohnwu/libsu.git)

It will work like a charm on every android

Hope it Helps.

Comment: is it possible to grant permission using su command ?

Comment: it will not work in android 14 OS device

Comment: Cannot run program "su": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: is your device rooted with magisk??

Comment: No, but i want not my full device root, only root specific application.

Comment: are you taking about https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk?tab=readme-ov-file?

Comment: only root specific application -> to grant root permissions to a specific application without rooting your full device , it is not possible your deice has to be rooted for even granting root privilages to a specific application

Comment: So i have to get root my device then i can get superuser permission or grant permission without popup am i right?

Comment: I think root application is possible because in play store there is many applications available which is cloning application - duplication of application, this is not possible without root application.

Comment: Root Application is not possible without actual root access to the device, the cloner you are talking abt are virtual containers and it is possible to clone app inside a cloner like BlackBOX or Octopus, and if you are talking abt apps which clone the other apps in main device is also possible in non root you just have to change package at one place in android menefest and tools like apktool can direct perform it without any root access

Comment: Thanks Aimar that is really great information. let me try magisk to root device.

Comment: i am just start researching on root device, it will honor to give some help regarding magisk to root device.

Comment: To Root a device with magisk is easy, you just need your bootloader unlock and flash the magisk zip in it , your device will be rooted, for questions regarding how to root im not much expert for every device you may raise another questions with separate tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257097/discussion-between-gaurav-mandlik-and-aimar).